# Implement authorization in rest server - design

Tags: java, rest, authorization

Our team has a REST server and a web application developed using Jersey. Currently we support only authentication in our application using OpenID [1]. We're planning to introduce authorization. In my research I found that role based authorization is one way we can implement this. This approach is to have our own tables like user, privileges and user_privileges and we assign users the required privileges (one to many mapping).

I have the following questions:

- Since we have a web application and a REST server. Should the authorization be implemented “inside” the REST server, or in the Web Application Server.
- Would like to understand the benefit of using Java's security frameworks like JAAS, Apache Shiro, OACC, Java security annotations [2] (@RolesAllowed) apart from code reuse ability, easy implementation.
- Would also like to receive recommendations on which framework to choose from the above mentioned (JAAS, Apache Shiro, OACC, Java security annotations) if suggested.

Thank you.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID 
[2] https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/security-javaee002.htm

Comment: what do you mean by REST server  here ?? can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: @kamleshpandey We have a REST API [Name: A] developed using Jersey. We have a web application [Name: B]. It is also a REST API which calls [A].

Comment: hope https://medium.com/@chrisbateson80/top-5-java-application-security-frameworks-to-build-secure-apps-e5256b45452b might help you

Answer (score 0):

As to your question: "Should the authorization be implemented “inside” the REST server, or in the Web Application Server": My recommendation is to implement it in neither! Instead, implement security inside the services that are called by your REST layer. In other words security is implemented in the very heart of your services, and is enforced regardless of how the service is called.

As for the security frameworks you mentioned, I am biased/partial to OACC. OACC provides a fully implemented API, uses an innovative design to seamlessly integrate with your application, supports a number of database back-ends to persist the security data, and is extensively tested with 1000+ integration tests.

This is a good article that discusses the OACC security model: https://dzone.com/articles/a-different-kind-of-java-security-framework

(*Disclosure: I am the creator/chief architect of the [OACC](http://oaccframework.org/) framework*)